# Operations on a string as a list element in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

A text file contains lines of text given in the format for each line
00:00;"Title";00
What I want to do is separate each line and then split each line at ;

```
text = open('text.txt', encoding='UTF-8')
lines = [x.strip() for x in text]
```

Now I am stuck, I cannot use:

```
separated = [x.split(';') for x in lines]
```

since x.split() is not applicable for list elements.
How can I perform operations on the list's elements?
Cheers

Comment: Why not just `lines = [line.split(';') for line in text]`?

Comment: Why not using a csv reader?

Comment: a mere beginner in python. Thank you for additional insight, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import csv
>>> list(csv.reader(lines, delimiter=';'))
[['00:00', 'Title', '00'], ['00:00', 'Title', '00'], ['00:00', 'Title', '00']]
```

Comment: Yes, this simplifies things a lot, thank you. It's not easy to look for a solution in csv, if one doesn't know what exactly to look for :)